# Sending and receiving UDP packets through NAT

Tags: c, sockets

I've been fiddling with this for a bit now. I have a server with a static IP address and a client sitting behind a consumer grade NAT (read a router provided by my ISP).
I'm trying to send a message, using UDP to the server and then receiving a response on the same socket. I have tried in a variety of languages, but just for the sake of it, here is my C version. I'm not sure if this a code problem or a machine configuration.

The message to the server goes through just fine, but the client never receives the response.
Client:

```
// Client side implementation of UDP client-server model 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT     8080 
#define MAXLINE 1024 

// Driver code 
int main() {
    int sockfd;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    char *hello = "Hello from client";
    struct sockaddr_in     servaddr;

    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
//    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("87.118.127.66");

    int n, len;

    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello),
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
            sizeof(servaddr));
    printf("Hello message sent.\n");

    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE,
                MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
                &len);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("Server : %s\n", buffer);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
// Server side implementation of UDP client-server model
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT     8080
#define MAXLINE 1024

// Driver code
int main() {
    int sockfd;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    char *hello = "Hello from server";
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));

    // Filling server information
    servaddr.sin_family    = AF_INET; // IPv4
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Bind the socket with the server address
    if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,
            sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int len, n;

    len = sizeof(cliaddr);  //len is value/resuslt

    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE,
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr,
                &len);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("Client : %s\n", buffer);
    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello),
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr,
            len);
    printf("Hello message sent.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a transport protocol and transport protocols carry a port. As you are working on this layer, the port has to be known/specified. But that is just not the case for `recvfrom` in your client code. It does not know from which port it should return the messages. Therefore you have to call `bind` and or `connect` in your client code.